# Having Troubles Modelling A Car

Tags: modeling

I can always put so much work into making a car but I always get stuck on making the roof go inwards and the hood. I can't find any tutorials that help me with this. To better explain say you are looking at the car from the front the car goes inwards at certain points I can't do that does anyone know a good tutorial or care to explain?

Comment: Please add images that show what you have and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/3cd79309c62f91272487a0a7abdf4205
What I'm talking about is see how it doesn't go straight up and down it has curves. I have no Idea how to do the curves on the front of a car.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT1GNMevfc
I found these tutorials extremely helpful and Darrin Lile is an excellent teacher.
Pete.

Answer (score 2):

subsurface modifier, in short. Dont think this can be answered with a quick answer though. You'll need to work your way through numerous modeling videos either on youtube or the many great training videos DVDs that exist for blender.